# Difference between Dell's XPS and Studio XPS laptops

Tags: laptop, comparison

My latest PC dates back from almost 4 years ago and I still love it. It's a XPS M1220. It's awesome because it's about the size of a netbook but, till this date, 3 times more powerful than the actual Dell netbooks.

Unfortunately, they don't sell computers like this so I'm looking at XPS 13 and XPS Studio 13. What are their differences? Which is lighter? which is the most scalable? What's the actual product segmentation? which is closer to my XPS M1220? Which offers a better performance to the money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one post at **MWolk** -- [**Difference between Dell XPS and Dell Studio**](http://mwolk.com/difference-between-dell-xps-and-dell-studio).
Compares **Dell XPS 1530** and **Studio 15** to highlight differences.

Summary from there.

- **Studio** is newer design, **XPS** is older best-selling model
- **XPS** has a **nVidia 8600 GT** while **Studio** has **Intel’s graphics card X3100**
- There are slightly different HDD options

---

This may be dated comparison.
I'd suggest you invite quotes from Dell directly.
That's always more helpful.